# Parse: Subclassing PFObject to the some data directly from Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm writing a swift iOS app that get data from Facebook and stores on Parse.com. Using the data stored on the PFObject I create a Graph API call and retrieve other set of data from Facebook at runtime. I cannot store all data on Parse because this second set can be updated frequently.

I was able to subclass PFObject to add my own properties and create a method that I can call and populate the PFObject with data from a Facebook Graph API call.

The problem is that I cannot find in the documentation the proper place to do the Facebook data loading. I cannot do this and "init" time, because the PFObjects are instantiated first and the date is fetched later using a PFQuery.

I'm thinking that maybe I should put this Graph API calls on a subclass of PFQuery, but the documentation advises against subclassing it. I didn't find anything about this.

Anyone had this kind of problem before?

Comment: Have you considered a container class that holds your data and logic, and has a reference to the PFObject?

Comment: Not really, because I'm using the PFQueryTableViewController to get all the "free" features from the framework and I think It only works with PFObjects. Maybe I'm missing something here? It's my first try with Parse.com framework.

Comment: Can you show some code? Depends how/when the PFObjects are created. Sounds like maybe you should be making the Facebook Graph API calls from Cloud Code (e.g. using an afterSave hook) so that it's retrieved and stored against each object once.